# How to create multiple objects in perl and access methods for same?

Tags: perl, object, hash, package

I was trying to create package with multiple methods and access them but it gives some hash values and expected?
following is code:

```html
package student_data;
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;
use Carp;

# init cell with cell name
sub new_student{
    my ($class,$args) = @_;
     my $self = { student_name => $args->{student_name} || 'default_value',  
          reg_number => $args->{reg_number} || 'default_value',
          dob => $args->{dob} || 'default_value',
          subjects=> {}
                 };

    bless $self, $class;
    return $self;
}


sub new_subject{
    my ($class,$args) = @_;
        my $self = { subject_name => $args->{subject_name} || 'default_value',
             credit => $args->{credit} || 'default_value',  
             grade => $args->{grade} || 'default_value',
                };
    #bless $self, $class;
    return $self
}

sub add_subject{
    my ($self,$args) = @_;
    my $sub1 = $self->new_subject($args);
    ++$self->{subject}{$sub1};
    return $self;
}

sub get_subject{
    my ($self, $args) = @_;
    #$self->{subject}{$sub1};
    return $self;
} 

1;

#use student_data;

my @all_students = ();

my $stud1= student_data->new_student({student_name =>"john",reg_number => "12"});

my $sub1 = student_data->new_subject({subject_name => "A" , credit => "3"}) ;
++$stud1->{subjects}{$sub1};

my $sub2 = student_data->new_subject({subject_name => "B" , grade => "50"}) ;
$stud1->add_subject($sub2);

push(@all_students, $stud1);

my $stud2= student_data->new_student({student_name =>"johnny",dob => "110388"});

my $sub3 = student_data->new_subject({subject_name => "B" , credit => "4"}) ;
++$stud1->{subjects}{$sub3};

my $sub4 = student_data->new_subject({subject_name => "A" , grade => "50"}) ;
$stud1->add_subject($sub4);

push(@all_students, $stud2) ;

my $et_stud = pop(@all_students);

print "\n student_name : $et_stud->{student_name} \n dob : $et_stud->{dob} \n subjects : $et_stud->{subjects}";
```

> student_name : johnny
>   dob : 110388
>   subjects : HASH(0x10301b8)

but I expect :

> student_name : johnny 
>   reg_number : default_value dob : 110388
>   subject_name : A
>   credit : 3
>   grade : default_value
>   subject_name : B
>   credit : default_value grade :  50

Comment: You are trying to write the code for students and subjects all in the same class. Your class names should start with a capital letter, and you need to write separate classes for `Student` and `Subject`. There is no need for multiple constructors, and you should just write `new` for each class.

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov: I suggest that it's being "oversmart" to guess who the downvoter was, guess what their reasons might have been, and then complain about your conclusions. Seriously, if you can't handle baseless downvotes then you shouldn't participate here, as it happens a *lot*. And it's likely to be people like you, who feel wronged by a vote, to then participate in drive-by revenge voting that just perpetuates the problem.

Comment: @Borodin, I apologize, if it wasn't you. I was fast to decide, but at the time almost nobody viewed the post except us. Whoever it was, he had to  clarify his action, anyways. But I still think that your notes were slightly off the point.

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov: *"Whoever it was, he had to clarify his action"*. No. Votes are anonymous on Stack Overflow, and it is no more acceptable to witch hunt the voters here than it is on a national election. *"I still think that your notes were slightly off the point"* If you ever think my words are off-topic, or simply wrong, then you should describe my mistake in comments. You may succeed in changing my mind or you may not.

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov: *"what goes wrong in his* ***working*** *example!"*. The OP's code works accidentally. I can explain why it works when it looks like it shouldn't, can you? It is exactly because of programming like this that we must always ***1*** define the API, ***2*** write the tests, and ***3*** test the code. Anything less will fail because of people who insist that a program is great because there is a *"working example"*.

Comment: @Borodin, I'm agree that the code must be properly organized, and should be beautiful. And you're obviously an experienced developer. But the question simply was: why the damned thing doesn't work. I've realized that you're a verbalist. I'm stopping the discussion as I don't want any more of this.

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov: Programming problems are often like a sudoku puzzle: once you have accounted for and tested all of the possibilities, you can be certain that your solution is correct. Ideally you will be able to build a complete system from provably-correct modules, but that rarely happens. We usually end up writing software that has myriads of possible inputs, which our experience and intuition tells us that we can reduce to something manageable. Being human, and so less than infinite, we are sometimes wrong. That is not because we are negligent, but because life is about guessing well.

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov: ***Verbalist***: "one who stresses words above substance or reality". I certainly don't value words for their own sake. What is the substance of your chide?

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov: ***"But the question simply was: why the damned thing doesn't work"***. But you're a *creator*, not a consumer. It is your customers that should be asking why something doesn't work, and you shouldn't be enquiring it of me. You can imagine [Matisse](http://totallyhistory.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/notre-dame-sunrise-by-matisse-large.jpg) asking the artist beside him for advice about his effort at a nostril, but not to keep his easel upright while he daubed.

Comment: @Borodin, okay. I apologize, again. Man, I'm sorry for being hostile =) You've got your point of view, I've got mine. Both have sense in this context. Probably, the best answer would be to first point to the root of the issue, then mention the best practices.

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov: Apologies are unnecessary. I make at least as many mistakes and, as I said, there are very many others who feel that their soul and essence has been challenged if they meet with dissidence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you're really a very long way off from understanding Perl object-orientation, and it's really hard to know how to help you other than just writing a working version

I've changed the structure of a `Student` object so that its `subjects` field is an *array* of `Subject` objects

I could see the worth of using a hash to avoid duplicating subjects per student, but that would involve error handling when there is none in your original. However you have added `use Carp` so I included code to use it to warn of incorrect arguments in the constructors

#### Student.pm

```perl
package Student;

use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Carp;

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my %args = @_;

    my $self = {
        name       => delete $args{student_name} // 'default_value',
        reg_number => delete $args{reg_number} // 'default_value',
        dob        => delete $args{dob} // 'default_value',
        subjects    => [],
    };

    carp 'Unexpected arguments ', join ', ', keys %args if keys %args;

    return bless $self, $class;
}

sub name {
    my $self = shift;

    return $self->{name};
}

sub dob {
    my $self = shift;

    return $self->{dob};
}

sub reg_number {
    my $self = shift;

    return $self->{reg_number};
}

sub add_subject{
    my $self = shift;
    my ($subject) = @_;

    my $subjects = $self->{subjects};

    push @$subjects, $subject;

    return $self;    # So that add_subject may be chained
}

sub subjects { 
    my $self = shift;

    @{ $self->{subjects} };
} 

1;
```

#### Subject.pm

```perl
package Subject;

use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Carp;

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my %args = @_;

    my $self = {
        name   => delete $args{subject_name} // 'default_value',
        credit => delete $args{credit} // 'default_value',
        grade  => delete $args{grade} // 'default_value',
    };

    carp 'Unexpected arguments ', join ', ', keys %args if keys %args;

    return bless $self, $class;
}

sub name {
    my $self = shift;

    return $self->{name};
}

sub credit {
    my $self = shift;

    return $self->{credit};
}

sub grade {
    my $self = shift;

    return $self->{grade};
}

1;
```

#### main.pl

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Student;
use Subject;

my @all_students;

my $student;

$student = Student->new( student_name => 'john', reg_number => 12 );
$student->add_subject( Subject->new( subject_name => 'A', credit => 3 ) );
$student->add_subject( Subject->new( subject_name => 'B', grade => 50 ) );

push @all_students, $student;


$student = Student->new( student_name => 'johnny', dob => '110388' );
$student->add_subject( Subject->new( subject_name => 'B', credit => 4  ) );
$student->add_subject( Subject->new( subject_name => 'A', grade => 50 ) );

push @all_students, $student;


my $et_stud = pop @all_students;

printf "student_name: %s\n", $et_stud->name;
printf "reg_number: %s\n", $et_stud->reg_number;
printf "dob: %s\n", $et_stud->dob;

for my $subject ( $et_stud->subjects ) {
    print "\n";
    printf "  subject_name: %s\n", $subject->name;
    printf "  credit: %s\n", $subject->credit;
    printf "  grade: %s\n", $subject->grade;
}
```

#### output

```
student_name: johnny
reg_number: default_value
dob: 110388

  subject_name: B
  credit: 4
  grade: default_value

  subject_name: A
  credit: default_value
  grade: 50
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `add_subject` function you're using the unblessed object returned by `new_subject()` as a key:

```
my $sub1 = $self->new_subject($args);
++$self->{subject}{$sub1};
```

But the keys must be scalar in Perl, so the object is converted to a string like `'HASH(0x1a1c148)'`.

If you want to store the objects, store them as values. For example, you might store an array reference in the object:

```
sub new_student {
  my ($class, $args) = @_;
  my @subjects;
  return bless {
    # other properties are skipped
    subjects => \@subjects
  }, $class;
}

sub add_subject{
  my ($self,$args) = @_;
  my $sub1 = $self->new_subject($args);
  push @{ $self->{subjects} }, $sub1;
  return $self;
}
```

Then you might iterate over the subjects freely:

```
print "subjects:\n";
foreach my $subj (@{ $et_stud->{subjects} }) {
  print "subject_name: ", $subj->{subject_name} // '(none)', "\n",
    "credit: ", $subj->{credit} // '(none)', "\n",
    "grade: ", $subj->{grade} // '(none)', "\n";
}
```

Second thing. You're examining the last item in the `@all_students` array - `$stud2` which has no subjects added.

You might want to check the number of the student subjects:

```
if (scalar @{ $et_stud->{subjects} }) {
  # run the loop...
} else {
  print "Student $et_stud->{student_name} has no subjects.\n";
}
```

(an array in scalar context returns the number of items.)